# Get 'last different value' of a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas dataframe in which I sort values of stocks into quantiles every month. I would like to make a column which shows the last different quantile a stock was in.

> Eg: If a stock went from quantile 1 to quantile 3, the "last different value" column value would
>   be '1' for this period. If after that it went to quantile 6, the "last different value" column
>   would show '3' for this period, as 3 would be the last quantile value which is not 6.

To ward off potential misunderstanding, you might be thinking I could just subtract the current month's quantile from the last month's quantile or show a 1-period lagged value but this wouldn't work 3 periods after something has changed quantiles, as I would still be looking for the last "different" quantile.

So I want to know how to get the last different value of a column as a value in another column.

The output should look something like the below, in which the "Last_Diff_Value" volumn shows the most recent value of the "Quantile" column which is not equal to the value of the "Quantile" column for the current period. The exception is when the quantile value has not taken on any other value except 1, then the "Last_Diff_Value" takes on the value 1. It can also be 0 or N/A in this case

```
d= {
    'Date':[ '01-2018', '02-2018', '03-2018', '04-2018', '05-2018', '06-2018'],
    'Quantile':['1','1','2','2','5','6'],
    'Last_Diff_Value':['1','1','1','1','2','5']
   }

df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
```

Comment: I'm not quite understanding your question. Could you please post a clearer expected output?

Comment: There is no quartile 6. There are only 4 quartiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### IIUC

Find where `diff`s are not zero, mask the rest and forward fill.

```
df.assign(
    Last_Diff_Value=
    df.Quartile.shift().where(df.Quartile.diff().ne(0)).ffill().bfill(downcast='infer')
)

      Date  Quartile  Last_Diff_Value
0  01-2018         1                1
1  02-2018         1                1
2  03-2018         2                1
3  04-2018         2                1
4  05-2018         5                2
5  06-2018         6                5
```